# Typescript parsing error when EXTEND_ESLINT=true in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, parsing-error, typescript-eslint

[Stripped down demonstration - GitHub](https://github.com/ae2438/cra-test)

We currently have a create-react-app project that is undergoing an incremental migration from Flow to Typescript. This meant disabling some undesirable ESLint rules. In order to customise ESLint, I've added `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` to the `.env` file.

Before adding this setting, my Typescript code compiles fine. Afterwards, I get parsing errors on certain (but not all) Typescript grammars.

```
// Type guards
export function f0<T>(x: T|undefined): x is T { ...

// Constrained generics
export function f1<T extends number>(x: T) { ...

// Type assertions
... return x as T
```

There may be other unrecognised syntaxes I haven't found yet.

**So far**

- I haven't found any similar problems or bug reports. I understand some Typescript features are not available in the current CRA version, such as `const enum`, but I haven't found any mention of the features listed above. I am also pretty sure my [Typescript and ESLint versions are compatible](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#supported-typescript-version) with `typescript-eslint`.
- I've tried many different `.eslintrc` combinations. I've left a few of the most promising in the `.eslintrc.js` file in the attached repository. The current setup is the one [recommended by create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config), where Typescript linting is set up in the `overrides` section.
- The ESLint Typescript configuration was set up following instructions from the [`typescript-eslint` monorepo](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/parser), in particular, [`typescript-eslint/parser`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/parser) and [`typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin)

**Solutions**

- Ejecting is not an option. If no other solution can be found, I would rather just do the Flow -> TS conversion in one go.
- We currently extend our CRA configuration with [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra). Solutions involving this are welcome.
- I enjoy the flexibility the `.eslintrc` gives me but I am happy to do away with it, provided I can still set lint rules.

**Notes**

- I've included `customize-cra` in the demo repo to accurately reflect our project, but the problem persists without `customize-cra`, indicating that it is likely not the culprit.
- See `src/components/TestComponent/fn.ts` for examples of the problem syntax.
- My current hypothesis is that there's some setup in the CRA ESLint config that doesn't get carried over when `EXTEND_ESLINT=true`.

**Updates**

- [I've opened an issue at create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7855)
- Partial workaround listed on the issue. Still not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: Update react-scripts to latest version at least 3.4.1.** It's fixed.

For pre 3.4.1 versions of react-scripts,

Open `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`

Replace code block from line 365 with this code.

```js
  if (process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true') {
    return undefined
  } else {
    return {
      extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
    };
  }
})(),
useEslintrc: process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true',
```

Now if you start your app by yarn or npm, you will see it is fixed.

The fix is originally introduced here

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7776#issuecomment-567587642

Run `npx patch-package react-scripts` to make a patch for it.
And add `"postinstall": "patch-package"` to your package.json scripts section.

**The patch will be automatically applied after `npm install`**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else encountering this issue, there is an [open issue at CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7776) which seems to be the cause.